Why does Xamarin iOS badge showns 1 over the icon and there is no notification?
I have a problem with iOS badge notification. It regular show the badge when a notification arrives but when there's no notification it still show the badge "1"
What is the problem and how can i handle it?
Edit: This is the only badge code i have.
UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound; UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);

How are you setting the badge? Local or remote notification? You need to explicitly set the badge to 0 at some point to clear the badge.

@Paulw11 the only thing im doing with the badge is enable it.
UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);

please read [ask] before posting.  Do not cram unformatted code into a comment - [edit] your question to include it and any other necessary information.

That code just requests permission to badge the app icon. You must then send a badge payload in your remote notification to set it to a specific value. To clear it you either need to send a remote notification with a badge value of 0 or use setBadgeCount to set it to zero.  When you do this depends on exactly what the badge count represents; unread messages, non-actioned notifications etc

@Paulw11 I really don't understand why i should send the badge on payload since the amount of notification varies per user. i know i can handle the setBadgeCount on code when i open the app via notification but can iOS handle the delete notification from the notification manager?

That's just how badging on iOS has always worked.  The notification payload contains an absolute badge number.  You might be able to use a UNNotificationServiceExtension to modify the badge payload when the notification is received.  You would need to use an app group to somehow share the data that the extension needs to compute the badge number from the main app.

With that problem you will have to make a mechanism to handle the notification count. MAUI has within its toolkit to make some actions with that. You can give it a look:
Maui Badge iOS
